# Get the content of tag's attribute as a unicode string in BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, attributes, tags, beautifulsoup

According to [`BeautifulSoup` documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes), it is possible to get the value of tag's attribute by using a code which looks like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<b class="boldest">Extremely bold</b>')
tag = soup.b

tag['class']
```

Theoretically (that is, according to the doc), the output would be :

```
u'boldest'
```

However, when I execute the above code, it outputs :

```
['boldest']
```

So, is there something I'm missing ? How can I obtain a tag's attribute content as a plain unicode string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tag['class'][0]
```

There are can be more than one class in tag, thats why it return list of values. If you sure there is only one class there - just get first element from list.

Answer (score 1):

Check this section in the documentation:

**Multi-valued attributes**

HTML 4 defines a few attributes that can have multiple values. HTML 5 removes a couple of them, but defines a few more. The most common multi-valued attribute is class (that is, a tag can have more than one CSS class). Others include rel, rev, accept-charset, headers, and accesskey. Beautiful Soup presents the value(s) of a multi-valued attribute as a list:

`tag['class'][0]` will give you the string